# What does お土産持しててね mean?

Tags: translation, meaning

I got a message from a friend, about to go on a trip, and it ended with: お土産持しててね

I think it's basically "[I'll] bring a souvenir/gift/omiyage [for you]" but I'm not familiar with the 持してて part, I've never seen it used like that before.

And if it does mean what I think, what is a polite way to say "you don't need to do that!". Would いいえ or maybe お土産話だけよ would be OK?

Comment: It is probability a typo, "持ってってね"

Comment: It may refer to [持{じ}する](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E6%8C%81%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B&dtype=0&dname=0ss&stype=0), though I think it's plausible it is a typo.

Comment: お土産持しててね does not make sense to me.  Although I suspect a typo, I have no idea what it is a typo for.

Comment: Just google "お土産持しててね", you would know that phrase does not exist.

Comment: `"[I'll] bring a souvenir/gift/omiyage [for you]"` --> Then it should be お土産[待]{ま}っててね (持→待, し→っ)

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a typo. Mayebe you should ask him what he meant.